# How to Disable Safe Mode using Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'd like to know if there's a way to disable going into safe mode on Android.

As an example, on a Samsung Galaxy S21, Google's Family Link app (used for parental supervision) does exactly this - when the app is running a user can no longer hold down on the power button in the UI to reboot in safe mode.

I have experience writing in Xamarin, and would appreciate any guidance - haven't been able to find anything on this yet!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a "dedicated device" situation (e.g. a phone used by certain workers as part of their job, or a kiosk)? If so, google `android app developer kiosk mode`. Or see https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices